# Return only desired columns from Sequelize.js with join

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I am switching from using node-mssql to Sequelize in order to access my database in a simpler fashion.  As a newbie to sequelize I am stumbling my way through pulling the correct data.

As I am converting a .net site with .net authentication to a node site I am using the existing authentication database.  Currently I am trying to pull all roles for an existing user.

Here is the code I have so far.  It returns both userID and roleID along with the username and role name that I desire.  How can I remove these 2 ID columns from my query results?

```
 test.aspnet_Users.findAll({
                logging: console.log,
                where: { LoweredUserName: `mcad2\\${user}` },
                attributes: ['LoweredUserName'],
                include: {
                    model: test.aspnet_Roles,
                    as: 'RoleId_aspnet_Roles',
                    attributes: ['LoweredRoleName']
                }
            }).then(user => {
                console.log('\n\n' + JSON.stringify(user))
            })
```

The database is set up so that both userID and roleID are contained in a third table, aspnet_UsersInRoles.  This is a relatively simple 2 join query but I am not certain how to make it work using sequelize.

Here is that sequelize-auto code which was created:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('aspnet_Roles', {
    ApplicationId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'aspnet_Applications',
        key: 'ApplicationId'
      }
    },
    RoleId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    RoleName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
      allowNull: false
    },
    LoweredRoleName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
      allowNull: false
    },
    Description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'aspnet_Roles',
    schema: 'dbo',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "aspnet_Roles_index1",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "ApplicationId" },
          { name: "LoweredRoleName" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "PK__aspnet_Roles__31EC6D26",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "RoleId" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('aspnet_Users', {
    ApplicationId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'aspnet_Applications',
        key: 'ApplicationId'
      }
    },
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    UserName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
      allowNull: false
    },
    LoweredUserName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
      allowNull: false
    },
    MobileAlias: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(16),
      allowNull: true
    },
    IsAnonymous: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    LastActivityDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'aspnet_Users',
    schema: 'dbo',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "aspnet_Users_Index",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "ApplicationId" },
          { name: "LoweredUserName" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "aspnet_Users_Index2",
        fields: [
          { name: "ApplicationId" },
          { name: "LastActivityDate" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "PK__aspnet_Users__03317E3D",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "UserId" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('aspnet_UsersInRoles', {
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'aspnet_Users',
        key: 'UserId'
      }
    },
    RoleId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'aspnet_Roles',
        key: 'RoleId'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'aspnet_UsersInRoles',
    schema: 'dbo',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "aspnet_UsersInRoles_index",
        fields: [
          { name: "RoleId" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "PK__aspnet_UsersInRo__35BCFE0A",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
          { name: "UserId" },
          { name: "RoleId" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

```
var DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;
var _aspnet_Applications = require("./aspnet_Applications");
var _aspnet_Membership = require("./aspnet_Membership");
var _aspnet_Paths = require("./aspnet_Paths");
var _aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers = require("./aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers");
var _aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser = require("./aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser");
var _aspnet_Profile = require("./aspnet_Profile");
var _aspnet_Roles = require("./aspnet_Roles");
var _aspnet_SchemaVersions = require("./aspnet_SchemaVersions");
var _aspnet_Users = require("./aspnet_Users");
var _aspnet_UsersInRoles = require("./aspnet_UsersInRoles");
var _aspnet_WebEvent_Events = require("./aspnet_WebEvent_Events");
var _aspnet_ZoneNumbers = require("./aspnet_ZoneNumbers");
var _aspnet_ZonePositions = require("./aspnet_ZonePositions");

function initModels(sequelize) {
  var aspnet_Applications = _aspnet_Applications(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_Membership = _aspnet_Membership(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_Paths = _aspnet_Paths(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers = _aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser = _aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_Profile = _aspnet_Profile(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_Roles = _aspnet_Roles(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_SchemaVersions = _aspnet_SchemaVersions(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_Users = _aspnet_Users(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_UsersInRoles = _aspnet_UsersInRoles(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_WebEvent_Events = _aspnet_WebEvent_Events(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_ZoneNumbers = _aspnet_ZoneNumbers(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var aspnet_ZonePositions = _aspnet_ZonePositions(sequelize, DataTypes);

  aspnet_Roles.belongsToMany(aspnet_Users, { as: 'UserId_aspnet_Users', through: aspnet_UsersInRoles, foreignKey: "RoleId", otherKey: "UserId" });
  aspnet_Users.belongsToMany(aspnet_Roles, { as: 'RoleId_aspnet_Roles', through: aspnet_UsersInRoles, foreignKey: "UserId", otherKey: "RoleId" });
  aspnet_Membership.belongsTo(aspnet_Applications, { as: "Application", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Applications.hasMany(aspnet_Membership, { as: "aspnet_Memberships", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Paths.belongsTo(aspnet_Applications, { as: "Application", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Applications.hasMany(aspnet_Paths, { as: "aspnet_Paths", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Roles.belongsTo(aspnet_Applications, { as: "Application", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Applications.hasMany(aspnet_Roles, { as: "aspnet_Roles", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Users.belongsTo(aspnet_Applications, { as: "Application", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_Applications.hasMany(aspnet_Users, { as: "aspnet_Users", foreignKey: "ApplicationId"});
  aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers.belongsTo(aspnet_Paths, { as: "Path", foreignKey: "PathId"});
  aspnet_Paths.hasOne(aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers, { as: "aspnet_PersonalizationAllUser", foreignKey: "PathId"});
  aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser.belongsTo(aspnet_Paths, { as: "Path", foreignKey: "PathId"});
  aspnet_Paths.hasMany(aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser, { as: "aspnet_PersonalizationPerUsers", foreignKey: "PathId"});
  aspnet_UsersInRoles.belongsTo(aspnet_Roles, { as: "Role", foreignKey: "RoleId"});
  aspnet_Roles.hasMany(aspnet_UsersInRoles, { as: "aspnet_UsersInRoles", foreignKey: "RoleId"});
  aspnet_Membership.belongsTo(aspnet_Users, { as: "User", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_Users.hasOne(aspnet_Membership, { as: "aspnet_Membership", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser.belongsTo(aspnet_Users, { as: "User", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_Users.hasMany(aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser, { as: "aspnet_PersonalizationPerUsers", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_Profile.belongsTo(aspnet_Users, { as: "User", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_Users.hasOne(aspnet_Profile, { as: "aspnet_Profile", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_UsersInRoles.belongsTo(aspnet_Users, { as: "User", foreignKey: "UserId"});
  aspnet_Users.hasMany(aspnet_UsersInRoles, { as: "aspnet_UsersInRoles", foreignKey: "UserId"});

  return {
    aspnet_Applications,
    aspnet_Membership,
    aspnet_Paths,
    aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers,
    aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser,
    aspnet_Profile,
    aspnet_Roles,
    aspnet_SchemaVersions,
    aspnet_Users,
    aspnet_UsersInRoles,
    aspnet_WebEvent_Events,
    aspnet_ZoneNumbers,
    aspnet_ZonePositions,
  };
}
module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an "exclude" option in the [attribute](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries) option of the query and exclude the given columns:

```
 test.aspnet_Users.findAll({
     logging: console.log,
     where: { LoweredUserName: `mcad2\\${user}` },
     attributes: { exclude: ['userID'], include: ['LoweredUserName'] },
     include: {
         model: test.aspnet_Roles,
         as: 'RoleId_aspnet_Roles',
         attributes: { exclude: ['roleID'], include: ['LoweredRoleName'] },
     }
     }).then(user => {
         console.log('\n\n' + JSON.stringify(user))
     })
```

If I understood your structure correctly this should exclude userID and roleID in the fetched data.

Comment: I actually didn't use this but rather reformatted my entire query and results handling in order to get the data I needed.  But this solution works as well.